# VB Script test without access to Windows Server

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this HTML page which I need to implement on an IIS 7 server but do not have the server to test with.

Can anyone help me as to whether this will work on the IIS server or if I need to turn on the setting for running classic ASP files.

VB Script:

```
<script language="vbscript">

sub hideall
    dim i
    for i=0 to document.all.length-1
        if instr(1,document.all(i).id,"pop")=1 then
            document.all(i).style.visibility="hidden"
        end if
    next    
end sub
sub L1_onclick()
        hideall
        intros.style.visibility = "visible"
        L1.style.color = "purple"           
end sub
sub  L2_onclick()    
        hideall
        pop2.style.visibility = "visible"
        intros.style.visibility = "hidden"
        L2.style.color = "purple"       

end sub
sub  L3_onclick()
        hideall
        pop3.style.visibility = "visible"
        intros.style.visibility = "hidden"
        L3.style.color = "purple"

end sub
sub init()  
    hideall()   
end sub
</script>
```

Menu structure as follows:

```
!--MENU1-->
<div style="LEFT: -20px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 270px; WIDTH: 190px">
    <ul class="list2">
        <li style="CURSOR: hand" id="L1"> 
        Introduction
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--MENU2-->
<div style="LEFT: -20px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 300px; WIDTH: 190px">
    <ul class="list1">
        <li style="CURSOR: hand" id="L2">
       Test 2
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--MENU3-->
<div style="LEFT: -20px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 330px; WIDTH: 190px">
    <ul class="list1">
        <li style="CURSOR: hand" id="L3">
        Test 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Content structure as follows:

```
<div id="intros" style="position: absolute; left: 170; top: 150; visibility: visible">
<object classid="clsid:166B1BCA-3F9C-11CF-8075-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/director/sw.cab#version=8,5,1,0"
 ID=introduction width=600 height=490>
<param name=src value="dswmedia/introduction.dcr">
<param name=swRemote value="swSaveEnabled='true' swVolume='true' swRestart='true' swPausePlay='true' swFastForward='true' swContextMenu='true' ">
<param name=swStretchStyle value=none>
<PARAM NAME=bgColor VALUE=#FFFFFF> 
<embed src="introduction.dcr" bgColor=#FFFFFF  width=600 height=490 swRemote="swSaveEnabled='true' swVolume='true' swRestart='true' swPausePlay='true' swFastForward='true' swContextMenu='true' " swStretchStyle=none
 type="application/x-director" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/"></embed>
</object>
</div>


<div id="pop2" style="position: absolute; left: 170; top: 150; visibility: hidden">
<object classid="clsid:166B1BCA-3F9C-11CF-8075-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/director/sw.cab#version=8,5,1,0"
 ID=torque reaction width=600 height=490>
<param name=src value="dswmedia/test2.dcr">
<param name=swRemote value="swSaveEnabled='true' swVolume='true' swRestart='true' swPausePlay='true' swFastForward='true' swContextMenu='true' ">
<param name=swStretchStyle value=none>
<PARAM NAME=bgColor VALUE=#FFFFFF> 
<embed src="test2.dcr" bgColor=#FFFFFF  width=600 height=490 swRemote="swSaveEnabled='true' swVolume='true' swRestart='true' swPausePlay='true' swFastForward='true' swContextMenu='true' " swStretchStyle=none
 type="application/x-director" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/"></embed>
</object>
</div>


<div id="pop3" style="position: absolute; left: 170; top: 150; visibility: hidden">
<object classid="clsid:166B1BCA-3F9C-11CF-8075-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/director/sw.cab#version=8,5,1,0"
 ID=tail rotor compensation width=600 height=490>
<param name=src value="dswmedia/test3.dcr">
<param name=swRemote value="swSaveEnabled='true' swVolume='true' swRestart='true' swPausePlay='true' swFastForward='true' swContextMenu='true' ">
<param name=swStretchStyle value=none>
<PARAM NAME=bgColor VALUE=#FFFFFF> 
<embed src="test3.dcr" bgColor=#FFFFFF  width=600 height=490 swRemote="swSaveEnabled='true' swVolume='true' swRestart='true' swPausePlay='true' swFastForward='true' swContextMenu='true' " swStretchStyle=none
 type="application/x-director" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

The purpose of the script is to switch the contents of the main div to show the different objects

Comment: Why don't you put it and try yourself?

Comment: I am not able to access the server to test

Comment: You can easily turn on the IIS server feature in windows for testing purpose. right?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't Classic ASP. `<script language="vbscript">` means you're using Client Side VBScript - it will be rendered by your browser rather than your server.  It will only work in Internet Explorer, other browsers don't support it.

Classic ASP is a technology which enables you to use a scripting language, (usually VBScript but sometimes Javascript) on the server. If you're using it you would indeed need to turn on ASP support as it's disabled by default on IIS7 and above. If you aren't running a version of Windows which comes with IIS then you can download IISExpress for use as a dev server